# Regex - How to group multiple lines until line starts with a string?

Tags: python, regex, regex-group

I have a text file like the following which I am trying to create some regex for in Python:

```
CR INFO
CR INFO
Wed Aug 17

foo-bar name_10_Name-Child_test
foo-bar name_25_Name-out
foo-bar name_1000_Name-test_out

CR INFO
CR INFO
Wed Aug 17

foo-bar name_10_Name-Child_test
foo-bar name_25_Name-out
foo-bar name_1000_Name-test_out
```

Now I'm fairly new to regex so apologies if this is very simple.

I'm trying to capture the lines starting with foo-bar, and grouping them together. So for example, the 3 foo-bar lines in one group, then the 3 below the date go in to another.

I so far have the following regex `(^foo-bar\s+[A-z0-9-]+)` but that matches every foo-bar line to an individual group, rather than having 3 in one group. Regex flags on regex101.com are gm.

How can I group the 3 lines together until it meets either the "CR" string, or a double new line?

Many thanks.

Comment: You write that you want to distinguish into two groups. If the blocks are always separated by at least two newlines, an idea: [`^((?:foo-bar.*\n?)+)|((?:.+\n?)+)`](https://regex101.com/r/aGMOzQ/1) (use with re.MULTILINE). I removed my answer because I'm unclear about the exact requirements and looks like it's solved already :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
^foo-bar\s+[A-Za-z0-9-].*(?:\n.+)*
```

Or, to make sure each next line start with `foo-bar` and whitespace:

```
^foo-bar\s+[A-Za-z0-9-].*(?:\nfoo-bar\s.*)*
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/KjjOul/3) / [regex demo #2](https://regex101.com/r/KjjOul/4). Use it with `re.M` / `re.MULTILINE` to make sure `^` matches the start of any line.

*Details*:

- `^` - start of a line
- `foo-bar` - a literal string
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `[A-Za-z0-9-]` - an alphanumeric or hyphen
- `.*` - the rest of the line
- `(?:\n.+)*` - zero or more non-empty lines
- `(?:\nfoo-bar\s.*)*` - zero or more non-empty lines that start with `foo-bar` and whitespace.

Note that [`[A-z]` matches more than just letters](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29771901/why-is-this-regex-allowing-a-caret/29771926#29771926).

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much. Explains it perfectly! Also, thanks about A-z meaning more than just letters, I thought it was all capital and lower case letters. Thank you.